# Método Assíncrono bloqueando Fila

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, assincronismo

Estou utilizando MVC e então abordei métodos assíncronos para ***Actions*** nas ***Controllers*** a fim de não bloquear o acesso a outras páginas do site enquanto um processo de longa duração esteja ocorrendo.

Porém, tenho tido problemas no seguinte cenário:

O processo de longa duração é uma finalização de Reserva e passa por diversos processos. Desta forma, criei a seguinte ***Action*** (que é chamada através de um ***POST*** via ***AJAX***):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Finalizar(bool? isMultiple)
{
    //obtendo os dados finais armazenados num tempdata
    var reserva = (ReservaViewModel)TempData["Reserva"];

    //chamada do metodo assincrono
    var result = await _reservaAsyncAppService.FinalizarReserva(reserva);

    //restando do codigo...
}
```

Tenho a seguinte ***Action*** que é a ***Home*** do Site, fiz de forma assíncrona:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.Portfolio = await _programaAppService.ListarPortfolioAsync();

    return View();
}
```

**Dúvida:** Quando inicio a Finalização da Reserva, em outra aba tento acessar a Home do site, porém, fica lendo por alguns segundos e quando acaba o processo de Reserva ele abre a Home.

Queria saber o porquê disto estar acontecendo, estou utilizando métodos assíncronos em ambas Actions, acredito que não deveria ter esse tipo de bloqueio na fila da requisição.

Percebi que ao iniciar a finalização da reserva e durante o processo em outro navegador acessar a **Home** ele abre normalmente, sem bloqueio de fila, mas ao iniciar o processo de finalização da reserva e tentar abrir a **Home** em outra aba do mesmo navegador o bloqueio acontece. Isto é normal ?

Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque [o ASP.NET MVC enfileira as requisições de um único cliente para não causar conflitos de variáveis de sessão](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/single-asp-net-client-makes-concurrent-requests-writeable-session-variables/).

Conforme o artigo explica, é possível implementar um `SessionStateStoreProvider` que não trave as demais requisições, mas não sei o quanto isso vale a pena para o seu caso.