# Problemas com Enfileiramento para Controllers Assíncronas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, async

Olá,

Estou tendo alguns problemas referente as Controllers Assíncronas, pois o **enfileiramento de requisições** do servidor continua sendo bloqueado para o cliente durante alguma operação. As rotinas funcionam de forma exata, consigo executar até mesmo funções paralelas (por exemplo, consigo jogar 4 buscas paralelas e aguardá-las utilizando (await Task.WhenAll(tasks);), porém, se a operação demora e eu tento acessar alguma outra página (alguma que tenha a Controller assíncrona), continua bloqueando e só libera a página quando a operação termina.

Um exemplo: o site possui um tipo de busca por produtos, fiz está rotina assíncrona, pois se demorar o usuário pode entrar em outra página sem problema de bloqueio. Há conseguia ir para outras páginas sem bloqueio durante a busca, até que um dia começou a bloquear o enfileiramento, quando isto ocorreu achei estranho e como estava em ambiente local, resolvi reiniciar a aplicação, apagando o cache e o histórico (acreditando que alguma coisa relacionada a isso poderia estar afetando). Após iniciar a aplicação novamente, não houve bloqueio durante a pesquisa e tudo estava funcionando no modo conceitual.

Porém, hoje aconteceu o mesmo problema e agora em ambiente de produção. Não sei se pode ser algum problema referente a threads ou com o próprio servidor. Tive problemas com bloqueios em Controllers que usavam sessões, mas em um [tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202763/m%C3%A9todo-ass%C3%ADncrono-bloqueando-fila/203400#203400) me explicaram que se há **session** existe um bloqueio por segurança.

Não sei se isso pode estar referente a alguma configuração no pool da aplicação (IIS) ou se é normal já que comecei a utilizar técnicas assíncronas há pouco tempo. Se puderem me esclarecer, agradeço.

Comment: Você usa `.ConfigureAwait(false)` após efetuar chamadas aos métodos assíncronos?

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira liberar os recursos mesmo sem eles terem sido 100% executados, basta trocar

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

por

```
await Task.WhaitAll(tasks);
```